# SSRS WebForms ReportViewer cancel button not working

Tags: reporting-services, webforms, autofac, reportviewer

I'm using the Report Viewer control for ASP.NET WebForms.  When a report is loading, it shows the loading indicator, with a cancel link.  But the problem is, this link doesn't do anything.  When I inspect the html, it is an `<a>` tag with no href.  I've seen other examples online that suggest there should be an href with some javascript here.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?  Why is this link not functional for me?

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms version 140.340.80

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being some type of incompatibility with Autofac.  I was able to restore the Cancel button functionality by removing the PropertyInjection module from web.config, and doing my Dependency Injection using another means.